# CoreAudio get output sample rate

Tags: core-audio

I'm creating a Mac OS X CoreAudio command-line program with proprietary rendering of some alphanumeric terminal input into a live audio signal, by means of AudioUnits, trying to stay as simple as possible. All works fine up to matching output sample rate.

As a starting point I'm using the Chapter 07 tutorial code of Addisson Wesley's "Learning Core Audio", CH07_AUGraphSineWave.

I initialize the AudioComponent "by the book":

```c
void CreateAndConnectOutputUnit (MyGenerator *generator) 
{

AudioComponentDescription theoutput = {0}; 

theoutput.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
theoutput.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_DefaultOutput;
theoutput.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;

AudioComponent comp = AudioComponentFindNext (NULL, &theoutput);
if (comp == NULL) {
    printf ("can't get output unit");
    exit (-1);
}
CheckError (AudioComponentInstanceNew(comp, &generator->outputUnit),
            "Couldn't open component for outputUnit");
AURenderCallbackStruct input;
input.inputProc = MyRenderProc;
input.inputProcRefCon = generator;
CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(generator->outputUnit,
                                kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback, 
                                kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                0,
                                &input, 
                                sizeof(input)),
           "AudioUnitSetProperty failed");

CheckError (AudioUnitInitialize(generator->outputUnit),
            "Couldn't initialize output unit");

}
```

My main problem is in my not knowing how to retreive the output hardware sample rate for the rendering AURenderCallbackStruct
since it does play a vital part in the signal generating process. I can't afford having the sample rate hard-coded into the rendering callback, although knowing it's the easiest way, since rate mismatch causes the signal being played at wrong pitch.

Is there a way of getting the default output's sample rate on such a low-level API?
Is there a way of matching it somehow, without getting overly complicated?
Have I missed something?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample-rate is a property of all AudioUnits - see `kAudioUnitProperty_SampleRate` (documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AudioUnitPropertiesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/I_O_Audio_Unit_Properties)) - although ultimately it's the IO Unit (RemoteIO on iOS or HAL unit on MacOSX) that drives the sample-rate at the audio interface.  This is not available in the call-back structure; you need to read this property with `AudioUnitGetProperty()` in your initialisation code.

In your case, the following would probably do it:

```
Float64 sampleRate;
CheckError(AudioUnitGetProperty(generator->outputUnit,
                                kAudioUnitProperty_SampleRate, 
                                kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                0,
                                &sampleRate, 
                                sizeof(sampleRate)),
```

If you're targeting iOS, you also need to interact with the [Audio Session](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 3):

When calling AudioUnitGetProperty, the 6th parameter must be a pointer to a variable that will get the size of the answer.

```
Float64 sampleRate;
UInt32 sampleRateSize;
CheckError(AudioUnitGetProperty(generator->outputUnit,
                            kAudioUnitProperty_SampleRate, 
                            kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                            0,
                            &sampleRate, 
                            &sampleRateSize),
"AudioUnitGetProperty failed");
```

However, as long as the sample rate has not been set, the function does not return a value (but there is also no error!)
You can however set the sample rate with for instance:

```
Float64 sampleRate = 48000;

CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(generator->outputUnit,
                                kAudioUnitProperty_SampleRate,
                                kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                0,
                                &sampleRate,
                                sizeof(sampleRate)),
"AudioUnitGetProperty failed");
```

From now on you can also read the value with the Get-call.
This does not answer the question, what the default value is. As far as I know that is always 44100 Hz.

Comment: Just for future reference the sample rate is not always 44100hz. I'm currently using a 2017 MBP that defaults to 48khz.

Comment: does `GetProperty` always return what has been set in `SetProperty` or will it return the actual sample rate? It seems like on some devices 44100 is not supported, so I am wondering whether in this case it will return the 44100 that were (tried) to set, or whether it returns 48000 (or whatever their default / fallback is)