# Method for determining current Hardware's Buffer Rate and SampleRate on OSX

Tags: macos, avfoundation, core-audio

I have a method that relies on knowing the hardwares sample rate and buffer duration in order to calculate some values.  Currently the implementation of this on iOS is as follow:

```
double sampleRate = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] sampleRate];
double bufferDuration = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] IOBufferDuration];
float bufferLength = sampleRate*bufferDuration;
```

However, on OSX, the `AVAudioSession` class is not recognized and does not appear to be part of the SDK.  And documentation about this sort of thing seems to be very scant.

How to I query the same values on the OSX OS?

Answer (score 1):

For determining buffer length, see this previous answer: [OSX: CoreAudio API for setting IO Buffer length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36546518/osx-coreaudio-api-for-setting-io-buffer-length/36552796#36552796) 
pointing at this Apple tech note about some Core Audio properties with getters and setters: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2321/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013499-CH1-THE_I_O_BUFFER_SIZE

For determining sample rate, see this previous answer:
[CoreAudio get output sample rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446571/coreaudio-get-output-sample-rate)
regarding the kAudioUnitProperty_SampleRate property.